# Accessing a list of viewcontrollers in the more tab of a tabbed view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So, I'm trying to get a list of the viewcontrollers in the more tab of the tabbed view controller, I then need to compare them to the current viewcontroller and check if the current viewcontroller is one of the ones in the more tab, I have tried this, but it doesnt work:

```
        NSArray *trialArray = self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.viewControllers;
    for (int i = 0; i != [trialArray count]; i ++){
        UIViewController *testController = trialArray[i];
        if (testController == self.presentingViewController){
            isIn = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Before going on about how Apple discourages having more than 5 items in the tabbed view controller yadi yada, I'm trying to make an accurate replica of the old iOS music app (almost done now, yay! (yes it has the cover flow)) which uses the more tab and a tabbed view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using this instead:

```
    if(self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBarHidden != TRUE){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by changing

```
if (testController == self.presentingViewController){
        isIn = 1;
    }
```

to

```
if (testController == self.presentedViewController){
        isIn = 1;
    }
```

Thanks.